# You have no eligible Bundle IDs for Mac OS X apps. Register one here

Tags: macos, app-store-connect

I get the error in iTunes Connect when I select:

`Manage Your Applications > Add New App > Mac OSX App`

> You have no eligible Bundle IDs for macOS apps. Register one here.

When I click on the "register" link, it shows one App ID that I have set up. All of the lights are yellow because my app does not use iCloud, Game Center or Push Notification.

Why is it not finding this App ID, or is there something I can do to "correct" it?

When I go to "Contracts, Tax and Banking", both Mac OS X Free and Mac OS X Paid Applications agreements are listed under "Contracts in Effect".

It seems to me that I have satisfied all prerequisites. What else is there?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Bundle ID needs to be different than the iOS version of the same app.

Comment: Same problem, but i haven't apps in my account. What i may do?

Answer (score 7):

Log out of iTunes Connect and log back in fixed it for me.

Comment: Unfortunately didn't fix it for me.

Answer (score 2):

This just happened to me (though the error was updated to "macOS apps" - which I'm including here for future solution seekers)

> You have no eligible Bundle IDs for macOS apps

It seems that for some reason Mac apps have their own section in the developer portal: switch to it before creating the App ID and it'll appear  immediately  in AppStoreConnect.

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

This issue appears to have reoccured again during the during the first week of January 2020.

This time, it was likely due to an error in the App Store Connect backend where it was not able to fetch the registered bundle ID from Apple Developer backend.

The same was reported to Apple by many developers (including myself) and the fix was applied by Apple on the backend servers.

A relevant discussion on the Apple Developer Forums can be found here:

- https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/127608